# How can I force to load a class that is only shown with the effect of JQuery in my Mediaquery?

Tags: javascript, html, css, media-queries, nav

I have an effect on my navigation whereas the navigition switches out after scrolling through the first window (`height: 100vh;/or 500px in the fiddle`). But the first nav is only interactable' on a mouse hover, which doesn't work for mobile users or people on tablets; I just want to make the second nav display on let's say widths below 900px; and kinda remove the first nav.

The second nav is only shown from Jquery/JS. With an if else statement; (if the window scrolls below 100vh height/500px in the fiddle, a class called full, which is the second nav) is added to the nav.

```
if ($window.scrollTop() > navShiftBreakpoint) {
            $navContainer.addClass( 'full' );}
     //full = the second nav & //navShiftBreakpoint = 500px
```

I made a [Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/0anpeLj0/3/), to visually explain the problem.

How can I fight this issue, any ideas?

Help and effort greatly appriciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This *technically* does not answer your question - as you requested the layout change using a media-query, but I did figure out a jQuery/JS solution.

If you check on load if the screen is less than 900px, and this is true, it will set the navbar to be like if you had scrolled already using the class you made. If this is not true, then it will call your original scroll function to change the layout after 500px.

```
(function() {

var $window = $( window ),
    $navContainer = $( '.nav-container' ),
        navShiftBreakpoint = 500; // px, when to change nav layout

if ($(window).width() < 900) {
    $navContainer.addClass( 'full' );
} else {
    $window.scroll(function() {
    if ($window.scrollTop() > navShiftBreakpoint) {
        $navContainer.addClass( 'full' );
            } else {
            $navContainer.removeClass( 'full' );
        };
        });
}
})(jQuery);
```

---

### ***EDIT:*** As per OP's request, here's an update to make sure that the layout 'updates' to the correct style when the screen size is changed, much like a standard media-query would do. This involved some resize events, but rather than explaining it, ***[view the updated JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/0anpeLj0/6/).***

---

Feel free to ask any questions.

Comment: Hey, any idea how I can fix this issue, so I can confirm that it works, but if I open it up on my screen (it has a `width: 1400px`) and then scale it down to let's say `width:450px`, where the second nav should come, it doesn't; only if I refresh it , it will force to come, any idea on how I can 'live' update it?

Comment: @ZanicL3 this should just be as simple as making it update on resize. I'll have a look into it and update my original post.

Comment: Alright cool, let me know when you have updated it, thanks for the effort

Comment: @ZanicL3 updated the post. I'm here if you have any other issues - happy to help!

Comment: thanks a lot that fixed it!! I really appreciated every single effort you did put in!